# iOS Game Center send friend invites

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, imessage

Since iOS 10 the Game Center app is removed as a application. The problem I am facing with the removal of the application is that I can't figure out how I can add Game Center friends.

> "You no longer add friends to Game Center. Instead, you invite people to play via iMessage for supported games. Game Center support is implemented by each app developer."

Is it possible to send a iMessage invite with in my application? And yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

After the local user is [authenticated](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW6) and you [present](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gamekit/gkmatchmakerviewcontroller) a GKMatchMakerViewController, the following screen will appear. Users can then invite friends via imessage by selecting the "Invite Friends" button in red below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After using GKMatchMakerViewController, you still need to add an event listener as well.